# New Stack Exchange top bar shows green achievements popup

Tags: support, design, top-bar

I like the new Stack Exchange top bar, but I have have noticed sometimes the Achievements popup icon is shown in **green**.

I am **not** talking about this one: [image]

Sometimes it shows this icon green:

[image]

like this:

[image]

Is it some type of feature or bug of Stack Exchange?

Note: I have notice it in Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a feature.

When you get an achievement that doesn't award reputation (for example, when you get a badge), the icon lights up green.