# Icons missing in achievements box

Tags: bug, status-norepro, top-bar, icons, achievements-dialog

I earned two badges today and intimated with highlighted green color in achievement bar, but icons in that box are missing and when I refreshed the page green color goes and shows the icons normally. I think it happening only when you achieved.

[image]

for better understanding check this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210891/new-stack-exchange-top-bar-shows-green-achievements-popup) for how achievement bar highlight.

As requested by one of the StackExchange member I posted the below screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning which site(s) the icons that are missing belong to.

Comment: @3ventic simply all icons in that box

Comment: I think you're being asked which site(s) you earned those badges on, since it's not apparent from the screenshot and it might be related to the reason that they're not showing.  Are they earned from StackOverflow, from SuperUser, etc.?

Comment: @Joe yes badges for stackoverflow and graphic design

Comment: Temporary hiccup in the connection caused [this sprite image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=f7871b368a51f63f0a5d42c19e901eab) not to load in your browser, resulting in all site icons not to appear. It also happens sometimes with `all.css` resulting in total mess. Refresh solves those issues and I don't think it's on Stack Exchange side.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your console and network tabs, showing the failure to load?

Comment: @Bala Nick isn't just "one of the mods", he's the programmer who wrote the code that cause those icons to appear in the first place, aka "dev" for Stack Exchange. Anyway that's not what he asked for, what you need is something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LtF99.png). In your case when it fails to load it will show different status than 200 and clicking it will give you full headers/error that might help Nick debug this.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thanks, I will try it in chrome, but tell me which addon I have to use in chrome

Comment: @Bala no addon, just click F12 and the tabs will appear, choose Network tab and you're all set.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I updated my post, thanks for the help!!

Comment: @NickCraver again I updated my post with correct info!!

Comment: @Bala better but still no cigar... Nick asked you "showing the failure to load", in the screenshot it's loading just fine. I fear you'll have to browse with the network tab always open and wait until it happens again if you want to catch the nasty bug. Of course nobody is expecting you to do that, reporting is just fine and Nick just wondered if you happened to take screenshot. (which you didn't :))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd last but not least, this is what I can do, check my update, thanks for your help and I found something broken and some warning

Comment: @Bala first one is just [the beacon I asked about recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210658/houston-we-are-web-bugged), second one is unharmful JS warning, both got nothing to do with missing icons. :)

Comment: Still nothing wrong in the screenshot, it's just showing that the sprites is taken from the browser cache as it should be.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think I need to do this test when I achieve next time and thanks for spending time with this.

Comment: Question is @Bala has this happened multiple times for you and when only displaying the Green Notification topbar state?

Comment: @Lankymart no this is the first time with new bar

Comment: @Bala Well I've just got the Green Bar myself for a Reputation change and my Achievements list appears with sprites showing, so I would suggest as ShaWizDowArd has that it was a connectivity glitch.

Answer (score 1):

As *@ShaWizDowArd* [mentioned in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210904/icons-missing-in-achievements-box#comment676979_210904), it's probably a one-time issue. The sprite image containing the icons ([this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=f7871b368a51f63f0a5d42c19e901eab)) probably didn't load in your browser and it caused the icons in the top bar not to appear. A normal page refresh should fix the issue.  If it does not, you could try a hard refresh by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

I'm unable to reproduce this issue on both Firefox and Chrome and probably others can't either, so I'm going to guess it's something at your end :)

Comment: you can't, because it showed me when I achieved the badges, give a try when you achieve !!!

Comment: @Bala: Did you try doing a hard refresh?

Comment: Please understand, it happened only when I achieved(gained badges) - meaning it will be highlighted with green color. so when I refresh it will show the non highlighted bar that works fine.

Comment: @Bala: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you able to reproduce this issue now? If you are: does a hard refresh fix it?

Comment: check the image I posted, it highlighted with green bar, still if you are unclear check this post what I'm talking http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210891/new-stack-exchange-top-bar-shows-green-achievements-popup

Comment: Think people are missing the point @Bala is pointing out that this issue only happens for him when displaying the ajax driven menu that fires when you receive an achievement. Going to be awkward to test without triggering the achievement top bar state.

Comment: @Lankymart yes exactly, I think some of them understood wrongly

Comment: @Bala I don't think it's related to you getting new achievements. You could have knocked on your screen twice and claim that's the cause. :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd not sure what you are implying? The issue could only really be tested by someone receiving the Green TopBar notification as the eventListeners in the page are tied to a websocket which facilitates the feature making it awkward to test. The question is does the TopBar notification state trigger different content and is that correctly linked to the sprite sheet.

Comment: @Lankymart it's the exact same content when fetched under any circumstances for a given user

Comment: @Lankymart Bala didn't see your comment, you can `@`-reply him now to let him know you asked something. :)

Comment: Will do ShaWizDowArd. Thanks for clarifying @NickCraver.